# C# Trakt.TV API Episode Scrobble

Tags: c#, oauth

I'm using the Trakt.tv api (http://docs.trakt.apiary.io) and attempting to scrobble a play.
I'm using Oauth. I seem to be doing exactly what it says in the docs, but keep getting a fail.

My response from POST https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/oauth/device/token after authorising my user is:
{"access_token":"{{accesstoken}}","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":7776000,"refresh_token":"{{refreshtoken}}","scope":"public"}

I'm then passing the above access token to Trakt.tv (/scrobble/stop)

POST https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/scrobble/stop
trakt-api-version: 2
trakt-api-key: {{APIKey}}
authorization: {{accesstoken}}

{"action": "scrobble","progress": 85, "episode": {"season": 1,"number": 1,"title": "Pilot","ids": {"trakt": 16,"tvdb": 349232,"imdb": "tt0959621","tmdb": 62085,"tvrage": 637041}},"show": {"title": "Breaking Bad","year": 2008,"ids": {"trakt": 1,"slug": "breaking-bad","tvdb": 81189,"imdb": "tt0903747","tmdb": 1396,"tvrage": 18164} }}

but keep getting the response of 401
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Doorkeeper", error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token is invalid"

Has anyone else used this API before successfully and can see anything I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `Bearer` in the `Authorization` header. Example listed at http://docs.trakt.apiary.io/#introduction/required-headers

Comment: Ahh ok. So if my access token is cfe345623 my Authorization header should be "Bearer cfe345623"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The `Bearer` text should be the prefix like that.

Comment: I'd also missed off the Content-Type: application/json but now works perfectly. Thank you. :-)

Comment: any example can be found somwhere how to get the `bearer` token?

Comment: @user3576148 http://docs.trakt.apiary.io/#reference/authentication-oauth